# Creating a variable in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to create a string, stored by a variable, whose value is determined by values in the URL. But, I am unsure how to go about it. I keep getting the error "unexpected T_IF". What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

PHP:

```
        $where=  

            if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
                echo "name=" . $name;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
                echo " AND number=" . $number;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['address'])) {
                echo " AND address=" . $address;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
                echo " AND city=" . $city;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
                echo " AND state=" . $state;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['zip'])) {
                echo " AND zip=" . $zip;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['color'])) {
                echo " AND color=" . $color;
            }
        ;
```

Comment: Why would you down vote, but not leave a comment?

Comment: This is a syntax error question. There are many like it and this one is no different. Syntax errors are always too localized because they've all been documented before http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+unexpected+T_IF+is%3Aquestion. Notice most of those questions have negative votes. StackOverflow is not your personal lint checker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare PHP variable like this. you have to concat the variable.

```
<?php
$where = '';
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $where .= " name=" . $name;
}
if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
    $where .= " AND number=" . $number;
}
if (isset($_GET['address'])) {
    $where .= " AND address=" . $address;
}
if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
    $where .= " AND city=" . $city;
}
if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
    $where .= " AND state=" . $state;
}
if (isset($_GET['zip'])) {
    $where .= " AND zip=" . $zip;
}
if (isset($_GET['color'])) {
    $where .= " AND color=" . $color;
}
echo $where;
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

I would simplify this a bit.

```
$whereElements = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) {
    $whereElements[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
$where = implode(' AND ', $whereElements);
```

If you don't want all the variables you could always whitelist/provide an array of keys to filter with.  Also, if you are using this in the context of SQL or something, you should really be using prepared queries instead, as this will be wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: This also avoids the string starting with `AND`, which would probably be undesirable.

Comment: +1 This is the best answer here.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
        $where=""; 

            if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
                $where .= "name=" . $name;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
                $where .= " AND number=" . $number;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['address'])) {
                where .= " AND address=" . $address;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
                where .= " AND city=" . $city;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
                $where .= " AND state=" . $state;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['zip'])) {
                $where .= " AND zip=" . $zip;
            }
            if (isset($_GET['color'])) {
                $where .= " AND color=" . $color;
            }
echo $where;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $where .= "name=" . $name;
}
if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
    $where .= " AND number=" . $number;
}
if (isset($_GET['address'])) {
    $where .= " AND address=" . $address;
}
if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
    $where .= " AND city=" . $city;
}
if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
    $where .= " AND state=" . $state;
}
if (isset($_GET['zip'])) {
    $where .= " AND zip=" . $zip;
}
if (isset($_GET['color'])) {
    $where .= " AND color=" . $color;
}
```

Basically, the `.=` tells PHP to tack on the value after the `=` to the end of what already exists in the variable.

In your question, you are using `echo` wrong. `echo` simply means write what follows on the page, not assign what follows to a variable.

Comment: But this only sets $where to the current variable being tested. I need it to accumulate.

Comment: The `.=` causes it to accumulate (technically "concatenate").

Comment: where accumulate actually means concatenate...

Comment: These will work and all, but say for instance `$_GET['name']` is not set, then your `$where` will begin with `' AND xxx=xxx'`. You may need to put more thought into doing this this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$where="";
```

and then

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $where .= "name=" . $name;
}
if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
    $where .= " AND number=" . $number;
}
if (isset($_GET['address'])) {
    $where .= " AND address=" . $address;
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have register_globals enabled (which is evil!), or your code will never work.

```
$where=
```

here you started an assignment, ...

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    echo "name=" . $name;
}
```

... and interrupt it with an `if` statement. That's why PHP is complaining.

The next problem is that you check the existence of one variable (`$_GET['name']`) but then use another one (`$name`).

Additionally, you're obviously trying to build (a part of) an SQL query without protecting your database from being hacked.

So, to simplify your code and make it more secure, change it to

```
// $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

$properties = array('number', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'color');
$conditions = array();
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    if (!empty($_GET[$property])) {
        $conditions[] = sprintf("`%s`='%s'", $property, $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET[$property]));
    }
}
$where = implode(' AND ', $conditions);
```